# IOS safari html5 video player controls over play button

Tags: ios, html, ipad, html5-video, mobile-safari

I'm developing a mobile application with cordova for, amongst others, IOS. In this application I'm using the HTML5 video player, but on my iPhone as well as my iPad the controls are situated OVER the play button. I can still press the play button, but seeking is harder than normal, and it just looks weird.

[image: controls over play-button]

Does anybody have an idea on why this is and what I can do to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this works fine on ipad 2/ios 7

Comment: Can you kindly provide the html and css of this player Sander

Answer (score 0):

Edit lib/ionic/css/ionic.css and remove/comment out the conflicting style attributes for `input[range]` Keep in mind that you will have to replicate the change in ionic.min.css for prod builds and/or if you update the ionic framework. Obviously you will have to come up with something less blunt if you are using or planning on using the Ionic framework's range input control styles.

```
ionic.css

/**
 * Range
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */

/*input[type="range"] {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  width: auto;
  height: 43px;
  outline: none;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #ccc), color-stop(100%, #ccc));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 0%, #ccc 100%);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 99% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-appearance: none; }
  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0; }
  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: -2001px;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #444;
    content: ' '; }
  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    padding: 30px;
    content: ' '; }

.range {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 11px; }
  .range.range-light input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #ddd; }
  .range.range-stable input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #b2b2b2; }
  .range.range-positive input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #387ef5; }
  .range.range-calm input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #11c1f3; }
  .range.range-balanced input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #33cd5f; }
  .range.range-assertive input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #ef473a; }
  .range.range-energized input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #ffc900; }
  .range.range-royal input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #886aea; }
  .range.range-dark input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #444; }

.range .icon {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0;
  flex: 0;
  display: block;
  min-width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px; }

.range input {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px; }

.range-label {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap; }

.range-label:first-child {
  padding-left: 5px; }

.range input + .range-label {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 0; }
*/
```